# MYSQL Database offline use

Tags: mysql, database, offline

Is there a way to use a MYSQL database without the database management system.. Like use tables offline without installing the db management system on the machine..
If there is can you please point me in the right direction? 
Thank you!

Comment: The short answer is "no". Why? What is your situation?

Comment: Well there is no "situation".. I'm just curious.. I was thinking that it would be nice to have the database file in an offile application for the data integrity, security benefits without actually installing the db management system on every machine.. Just create a database file once in MYSQL and attach it to my application..

Comment: some programming languages have sqlite, a lightweight mySQL implementation that is file based. Other than that, nope - there is no way to run mySQL without a mySQL server

Comment: Using MySQL without a MySQL server is possible (it's called embedded MySQL server) and makes perfect sense, for example to build a stand-alone application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this.

However, there is a portable DBMS [SQLIte](http://www.sqlite.org/). It comes in different ways and can be used on other platform  with different programming languages.

After reading your comment, I'm almost sure, this is what you need.
It's not that fast as MySQL I guess, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [The embedded MySQL Server Library](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/libmysqld.html) to access MySQL data files without running the MySQL server.

Comment: The link doesn't exist anymore https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/libmysqld.html

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a database to work on your localhost. This will be offline unless you setup the front-end stuff to let the internet interact with it.

What exactly do you mean "without the database management system"? You always need a way of interacting with it, even if it is offline. (Otherwise how can it work for you?)

Comment: Well I thought that for example using Qt that has drivers for databases I could use a database without mysql being installed on the system.. I think you can use C# and MSSQL's mdf files like that.. Not sure though..

Comment: I'm honestly not too familiar with that topic. I thought you meant installing a database (like mysql) locally so you could use it on your own machine. In that situation, you can definitely be offline.

Answer (score 0):

The server side piece of the application, mysql-server, is needed at a minumum to run mysql. This server application comes with all the tools *built-in* to manage the instance. I doubt you can prevent installation of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you've actually opened the table files in a hex or text editor, you'll see that you will definitely need the mysql application installed to make any sense of them to use them.  Sure the records are all there in plain text (.myd files for myisam, the ibdata1 file for innodb tables), but it would be a complete time-waster devising a custom app to parse or update the file structure, as well as trying to tie in table structure contained in the related files for each table.